# How to select all files inside a folder on Toolbar item click

Tags: java, android, view, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview

I have a toolbar with an option of *Select All*. I am trying to select all files inside a folder on clicking *Select All* and change background color of gridview items being displayed on screen. But I don't know how to achieve this.
Some answers on this site suggested to use `getview()` inside adapter .
But then, I can't figure out, how to access get view from Mainactivity. If I write `adapter.getview()` in Main activity to access it, then what parameters need to be passed inside `getview()`.
Or should I create an interface ? If yes, how to access `getview()` with the help of that ?
Any suggestions would be of great help . Thanks

Adapter class :  GridviewAdapter.java

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model_images> {

    Context context;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();
    int int_position;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu,int position) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_adapter__photos_folder, al_menu);
        this.al_menu = al_menu;
        this.context = context;
        this.int_position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.e("ADAPTER LIST SIZE ", al_menu.size() + "");
        Log.e("ADAPTER LIST SIZE", al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size() + "");
        return al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size();
    }

    public void updateUpdater(ArrayList<Integer> mSelected) {
        for (int selected : mSelected) {
            File file = new File(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(selected));
            file.delete();
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,new String[] { file.toString() }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener()
            {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)
                {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });


                        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        if (al_menu.size() > 0) {
            return al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size();
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        File file2 = new File(al_images.get(int_position).getDirectoryPath());
        if(file2.isDirectory()){
            String[] fileNames = file2.list();
            for(int a=0;a<fileNames.length;a++){
               convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }
        }
        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_adapter__photos_folder, parent, false);
            viewHolder.tv_foldern = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder);
            viewHolder.tv_foldersize = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder2);
            viewHolder.iv_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tv_foldern.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.tv_foldersize.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        Glide.with(context).load("file://" + al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(viewHolder.iv_image);


        return convertView;

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_foldern, tv_foldersize;
        ImageView iv_image;

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you not using recycle view?

Comment: is it necessary to use that ? @farhana I am trying to do it with gridview , if possible

Comment: yes, you can get better functionality in recycle view adapter and recycle view click and of course, you can use Recycle view as grid layout and you get many examples in multi-selection or select all.

Comment: is it not possible to do that with simple gridview @farhana

Comment: You can do it with Grid view but Recycleview gives you better click listener and listener.